# Nuxt. Does not work js when the Internet is weak

Tags: nuxt.js

I am developing an application in nuxt.js. I make `yarn generate`, then I distribute the statics. And everything works. But if I set trottling:LTE in Network of devtools, then the Java script does not work. Tell me, what could be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working ? Is it fully loaded ? A throttle should just make things slow but still allow it to work properly, if there is no timeout of course.

Comment: @kissu As it turned out, after a while everything works. The application needs optimization. The question is closed.